# how to set callback of post request in react with redux, redux-thunk and axios?

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm trying to do async post request to update my data only after success.

what I want is to use promise type thing in action call.

```
this.props.postAction('/event/user/44/post',data)
.then((response) =>{
  console.log("Inside callback"); 
  console.log(response);
});
export default connect({postAction})(EventFeed);
```

here is my action file where I'm making post request

```
export const POST_ACTION = 'POST_ACTION';

export function postAction(url,data) {
  return function(dispatch) {
      axios({
          method:'post',
          url:API_URL + url,
          headers: {'event': 55},
          data: data,
      })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_ACTION,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

But I'm never getting inside callback.

Now how to make callback to get data from response???

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should't. You are violating the whole idea behind [Unidirectional dataflow](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html). When using Redux your async stuff should be handled in the action creator alone, it dispatches actions with potential data payload, the store gets updated and the app re-renders. When you are reaching out and "back" via a promise chain your violating that flow.

With that warning said, you are not returning the promise from your thunk. You should also return your responses when chaining then's. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```
export function postAction(url,data) {
  return function(dispatch) {
      //You need to return your promise.
      return axios({
          method:'post',
          url:API_URL + url,
          headers: {'event': 55},
          data: data,
      })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_ACTION,
        payload: response.data
      });
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for theese kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can pass a callback function as a parameter to the redux action

```
export const createUser = (user, callBack) => {
    api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = state.token.token;
    api.post("/users/create", user)
        .then(response => {
            //dispach(createUserSuccess(response.data));
            if (callBack !== undefined) {
                callBack(response.data, null);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            error = errorManager(error);
            //dispach(createUserFailure(error));
            if (callBack !== undefined) {
                callBack(null, error);
            }
        });
}
```